# Using Typescript Generics to restrict a functions input parameter

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

## Problem

I have created a Typescript package that shares types between my backend node firebase cloud functions and my fronted React client that calls them. Below are some samples of the types.

```
interface FirstFunctionInput {
  x: number
}

interface SecondFunctionInput {
  y: string
}

// defines all available functions
enum FirebaseFunction {
  FirstFunction = "firstFunction",
  SecondFunction = "secondFunction"
}
```

This is how I am calling the functions currently, using the [firebase sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase):

```
firebase.funtions.httpsCallable('firstFunction')({ x: 21 })
  .then(result => { ... })
```

My problem here is

1. There is no guarantee that the function 'firstFunction' exists
2. Even if it does, how can I be sure that it accepts a parameter such as `{ x: 21 }`.

#### So what I am trying to achieve is a way to write a utility method using Generics that overcomes these problems.

## Ideal solution

Below is an example of how I'd (ideally) like the API to look. I have provided an example where the wrong input type is provided to the function, and I expect Typescript to show an error.

```
callFirebaseFunction<FirstFunction>({ y: 'foo' })
                                    ^----------^
                    show error here, since FirstFunction must take a FirstFunctionInput
```

## Current (but not quite there yet) solution

I have come close to achieving this, with an API that works, however it requires the input params to be specified at the calling location:

```
callFirebaseFunction<FirstFunctionInput>(
  FirebaseFunction.FirstFunction,
  { x: 21 }
)
.then(result => { ... })
```

This is not ideal because the input type needs to be known by the programmer, in order to specify it.

### Final Words

I have tried all different combinations of interfaces that are extended, abstract classes that are extended and even the builder pattern, but I cannot find a way to tie this all together. Is something like this even possible?

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbkyBW) meet your needs?  If so, I'll write up an answer.  If not, please elaborate on exactly what is missing, preferably with a [mcve] version suitable for dropping as-is into a standalone IDE where the issue is demonstrated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is no generic used in `httpsCallable`, we should wrap it with function and use generic to restrict the type.

Some knowledge about [Currying](https://javascript.info/currying-partials) will be used here, in this way, its structure is the same as original.

```js
interface FirstFunctionInput {
  x: number
}

interface SecondFunctionInput {
  y: string
}

interface FunctionInputs {
  firstFunction: FirstFunctionInput,
  secondFunction: SecondFunctionInput
}

function callFirebaseFunction<K extends keyof FunctionInputs>(fn: K) {
  return function (input: FunctionInputs[K]) {
    return firebase.functions().httpsCallable(fn)(input);
  };
};

callFirebaseFunction('firstFunction')({ x: 1 }) // OK
callFirebaseFunction('secondFunction')({ y: '1' }) // OK
callFirebaseFunction('test')({ x: 1 }) // ERROR
callFirebaseFunction('secondFunction')({ x: true }) // ERROR
```

---

#### Additional Update

If you want to specify the type of output, that is to say

```
allFirebaseFunction('firstFunction')({ x: 1 }).then((res) => /* specify type of res */)
```

Due to the type of `HttpsCallableResult` is such a interface in source code:

```
export interface HttpsCallable {
    (data?: any): Promise<{data: any}>;
  }
```

Then the type of output extending `{data: any}` would be better.

Finally, we can achieve that like following:

```
interface FunctionInputs {
  firstFunction: {
    input: FirstFunctionInput,
    output: { data: number }
  },
  secondFunction: {
    input: SecondFunctionInput,
    output: { data: boolean }
  }
}

function callFirebaseFunction<K extends keyof FunctionInputs>(fn: K) {
  return function (input: FunctionInputs[K]['input']): Promise<FunctionInputs[K]['output']> {
    return firebase.functions().httpsCallable(fn)(input);
  };
};

callFirebaseFunction('firstFunction')({ x: 1 }).then(res => { /* { data: number } */ })
callFirebaseFunction('secondFunction')({ y: '1' }).then(res => {/* { data: boolean } */ })
```

Comment: This is awesome and is working great! I actually have a follow up question and wondering if you can help?

I would like to extend this functionality so that I can specify both the input, as well as the expected output.

Would you have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: To restrict type of result of Promise? like this one? `callFirebaseFunction('firstFunction')({ x: 1 }).then((res) => /*  restrict type of res */)`

Comment: yes exactly like that. I thought once I get the first part solved I'll extend the solution to include the return types, but I have never seen currying before and I am struggling to do this as well..!

Comment: sure thing, wait a sec, I am updating my answer

Comment: this is brilliant - thank you so much. You have both solved my problem and taught me something!

As a final question, more out of interest as I don't think it's necessary, would there be a way to enforce that each function defined inside the `FunctionInputs` includes both `input` and `output`, and shows an error if one is missed? Perhaps by even making an base function `interface BaseFunction { input: (what type goes here?) output: (another type goes here?) }` and then for each firebase function, create an interface that extends it?

Comment: If extends it, `callFirebaseFunction('test')({ x: 1 })` will not show any error possibly, so you can try generics to define this `type BaseFunction<Input, Output> = { input: Input; output: { data: Output } }`, and then define `firstFunction...` with it.